# TDD with NHibernate

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, nhibernate, tdd

I want to start a test driven development with ASP.Net 3.5 (C#), NHibernate with Oracle and NUnit. Can any body refer me any tutorial about NHibernate with NUnit for beginning. Any book reference will also be appreciated.

N.B. I have seen the summer of Nhibernate video series, but it works for SQL server only not oracle.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to test Nhibernate or the database? Why would you have it in your unit tests?

Comment: I want to use NHibernate with the Database and test the data transaction using NHibernate.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to mock up the database, instead of relying on it for your tests? This will allow you to make sure specific calls are made.

Comment: @Yuriy Faktorovich: It's very useful to create integration test to test if your code is actually working with your database. When you mock something out when used as a dependency, you have to create test for the mocked out thing as well.

Comment: @Paco: Why would you have to create a test for the mock? Why not just use a general mock framework?

Comment: @Yuriy Faktorovich: I don't mean a test for the mock itself, but for the mocked out code. If you use a mock to test an IRepository dependency, you need another set of tests to test the individual methods of the IRepository implementation. When you just mock everything, your tests will become useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**This tutorial**](https://web.archive.org/web/20081212181310/http://blogs.hibernatingrhinos.com/nhibernate/archive/2008/04/01/your-first-nhibernate-based-application.aspx) could use a teeny bit of editing, but it's quite good and it's exactly what you're looking for: a step-by-step NHibernate tutorial using test-driven-development methods.

Comment: But still getting problem with oracle :(

Answer (score 1):

To learn more about nhibernate I would watch the summer of nhibernate casts.
http://www.summerofnhibernate.com/

Maybe look at this question:
[NHibernate TDD with oracle in ASP.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178439/nhibernate-tdd-with-oracle-in-asp-net/2201945#2201945)

Some other useful links I have used in the past.

http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/your-first-nhibernate-based-application.aspx

http://tiredblogger.wordpress.com/2008/11/07/using-oracle-odp-with-nhibernate-from-a-c-class-library/

http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers

Answer (score 0):

For doing TDD with NHibernate, it can be useful to set up you database into specific scenarios. One technique I've used is [using an In-Memory SQLite database](http://blog.jstaten.com/memory-database-testing-sqlite-nhibernate/). Because a fresh database is created for each test, you don't have to worry about inconsistent results from running tests multiple times that a persistent database can cause. Also, the test code is redistributable without the requirement of someone else to be running an instance of Oracle, SQL Server, etc.

On a side note, integration testing with the actual database is important because behavior can differ slightly, even with a nice ORM like NHibernate.

Comment: I'm also testing with SQLite in-memory. And I'm also in an Oracle environment. As statenjasen says, the two differ, so it doesn't replace integration tests completely (you can't use multi-queries with Oracle for example).